# How to calculate numbers in string from DB in PHP

Tags: php

I echo some numbers from the database and show only those numbers with a foreach. I now want to calculate the total of these numbers.

```
$test = str_replace('\\', '', $orderDetails['jsonData']);
$bonbonOrders = unserialize($test);

foreach($bonbonOrders as $bonbonOrder){
    foreach($bonbonOrder as $bonbons){
        echo $bonbons['gewicht'];
    }
}
```

I tried several things but I really don't know how I can calculate them.

the output for a example can be:

```
18 15 16 12 11
```

Thanks!

Comment: explode(), foreach(), basic math...

Comment: I'm not a hero with php at all so I don't know what you mean, sorry.

Comment: if that's literal DB output, then op has multiple values in a single field, and sum/count won't work, since the db's not normalized. 'course, maybe that's multiple values on a single line due to lack of linebreaks in the echo, but who knows...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends how you are getting those numbers from your database. However, since you are deserializing something I will assume that it cannot be done in a simple SQL query.

The following code should echo out the total of all of the numbers.

```
$test = str_replace('\\', '', $orderDetails['jsonData']);
$bonbonOrders = unserialize($test);

$nums = array();
foreach($bonbonOrders as $bonbonOrder){
    foreach($bonbonOrder as $bonbons){
        $nums[] =$bonbons['gewicht']; 
    }
}
$total = array_sum($nums);
echo $total;
```

Achieved by adding all of the numbers to an array, and calling `array_sum` on the final array.

Another alternative would have been to create `$total = 0` before the `foreach` and to simply increment it as you get access to each number.

Answer (score 1):

Simply addup each `$bonbons['gewicht']` value in a variable and echo it

```
$test = str_replace('\\', '', $orderDetails['jsonData']);
$bonbonOrders = unserialize($test);
$sum =0;
 foreach($bonbonOrders as $bonbonOrder){
  foreach($bonbonOrder as $bonbons){
    echo $bonbons['gewicht'];
    $sum += $bonbons['gewicht'];
   }
 }

 echo $sum;
```